# Mysql Find missing date ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with date ranges:

```
    create table d (
    date_start date,
    date_end date
    );

    insert into d values('2014-03-05', '2014-04-10');
    insert into d values('2014-05-01', '2014-06-05');
    insert into d values('2014-07-10', '2014-08-15');
```

I want to complete this table with missing date ranges in 2014. In this case that would be:

```
    2014-01-01 - 2014-03-04
    2014-04-11 - 2014-04-30
    2014-06-06 - 2014-07-09
    2014-08-16 - 2014-12-31
```

Any mysql query suggestions?

**Edit**

Better use these values:

```
    create table d (
        date_start date,
        date_end date
        );

        insert into d values('2014-06-01', '2014-06-30');
        insert into d values('2014-07-01', '2014-08-03');
        insert into d values('2014-09-01', '2014-09-30');
```

**Edit 2**

I am almost there with this:

```
    SELECT
            date_start,
            date_end

    FROM

    (SELECT 
      ends.point AS date_start,
      starts.point AS date_end
    FROM 
      (SELECT 
        d.date_end+INTERVAL 1 DAY AS point, 
        @n:=@n+1 AS num 
      FROM 
        d 
          CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n:=1) AS init0
          ORDER BY date_start
      ) AS ends 
      INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT 
        d.date_start-INTERVAL 1 DAY AS point, 
        @m:=@m+1 AS num 
      FROM 
        d 
          CROSS JOIN (SELECT @m:=0) AS init1
          ORDER BY date_start
      ) AS starts 
      ON ends.num=starts.num
    UNION ALL 
      SELECT 
      '2014-01-01', 
        MIN(date_start) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
      FROM 
        d 
      WHERE 
        date_start>='2014-01-01'
    UNION ALL 
      SELECT 
        MAX(date_end)+INTERVAL 1 DAY, 
        '2014-12-31'
      FROM
        d 
      WHERE 
        date_end <= '2014-12-31'
    ) as dates
    WHERE
      date_start < date_end
    ORDER BY 
      date_start;
```

However, this query returns wrong results for the following intervals set:

```
    create table d (date_start date, date_end date);

    insert into d values('2014-01-01', '2014-01-09');
    insert into d values('2014-01-10', '2014-03-15');
    insert into d values('2014-03-16', '2014-04-20');
    insert into d values('2014-05-01', '2014-07-30');
    insert into d values('2014-08-01', '2014-09-30');
    insert into d values('2014-12-25', '2014-12-31');
```

It seems it cannot handle single days like 2014-07-31 - 2014-07-31.

Comment: Can your intervals intersect or be nested?

Comment: Sorry, the intervals may be consecutive, e.g. 2014-06-01 - 2014-06-30; 2014-07-01 - 2014-07-31. But they never overlap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case if your date intervals will not be nested or intersecting, you can use trick with `JOIN` to produce result set. So, to select desired record set, you'll need:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(SELECT 
  ends.point AS date_start, 
  starts.point AS date_end 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
    d.date_end+INTERVAL 1 DAY AS point, 
    @n:=@n+1 AS num 
  FROM 
    d 
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n:=1) AS init0
  ) AS ends 
  INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT 
    d.date_start-INTERVAL 1 DAY AS point, 
    @m:=@m+1 AS num 
  FROM 
    d 
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @m:=0) AS init1
  ) AS starts 
  ON ends.num=starts.num 
UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
    '2014-01-01', 
    MIN(date_start) - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS date_end
  FROM 
    d 
  HAVING 
    date_end>'2014-01-01' 
UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
    MAX(date_end)+INTERVAL 1 DAY AS date_start, 
    '2014-12-31' 
  FROM
    d 
  HAVING 
    date_start<'2014-12-31' 
) as dates
WHERE
  date_start<=date_end
ORDER BY 
  date_start;
```

that will result in

```
+------------+------------+
| date_start | date_end   |
+------------+------------+
| 2014-01-01 | 2014-03-04 |
| 2014-04-11 | 2014-04-30 |
| 2014-06-06 | 2014-07-09 |
| 2014-08-16 | 2014-12-31 |
+------------+------------+
```

([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47760/1) for this is here)

To "complete" your table you may use [`INSERT..SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) syntax with `SELECT` query above.

Comment: This works almost fine, but gives wrong result e.g. 2014-07-01 - 2014-06-30 when there are consecutive periods, say 2014-06-01 - 2014-06-30; 2014-07-01 - 2014-07-31. Gave an example of set of periods in my original post edit.

Comment: @Victor you've said they won't intersect (and yes, consecutive periods case _is an intersection_). Anyway, I've updated (fiddle link too). It's not too hard to handle this case of intersection

Comment: Then I was wrong perhaps. Yes, they won't overlap, but may be consecutive.

Comment: I see this really did the trick! Thanks a lot! By the way, this was needed for a property rental engine with seasonal prices (see original question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927260/mysql-seasonal-pricing-for-apartment-booking) ).

Comment: Found that it cannot handle single days like 2014-07-31 - 2014-07-31. Updated my post with your slightly updated code as I have it now. When there is a period of just a single day, it shows incorrect results.

Comment: Well.. it's even not correct interval. Anyway, I've updated (using `HAVING` to exclude such case)

Comment: Did not work for me, however I changed "WHERE date_start<date_end" to "WHERE date_start<=date_end" at the end of your first query (without having) and it worked, at least in this particular case. Do you think this is correct? Still testing.

Comment: No, this should work well. Your case with consecutive intervals is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/761c96/5) - it seems, you've not tried updated query (I've did edits in post itself)

Comment: I understand that technically 1 day is not an interval, but the task is to fill the whole year, no gaps)

Comment: I can see the updated code and fiddle, but it shows only two rows for me, missing 2014-07-31 - 2014-07-31.

Comment: Oh, finally got what is wrong. Just [change `<` to `<=`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/761c96/6). It's incorrect technically, but will do the trick.

Comment: That's it! Thank you, I am still testing different scenarios and will let you know if anything goes wrong.